# How to pass data to view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Im passing data to my blade view with `return View::make('blog', $posts);` and in my blade view I'm trying to run an `@foreach ($posts as $post)` I end up with an error saying that `$posts` isn't defined.

My question is how would the `$posts` array be called?

Comment: `return View::make('blog',compact('posts'));`

Comment: To be clear, the 2nd parameter needs to be an associative array: `array('posts' => $posts)`, or you can use the `with()` method as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: `return view('blog',compact('posts'));`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can pass data to the view using the `with` method.

```php
return View::make('blog')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Comment: How to pass collection ?

Comment: How to get it on view?

Comment: @MadhuramanGhimire write @foreach($posts as $post){ {{$post->title}} {{$post->author}} } or any other data that you need in the view.

Answer (score 88):

As of Laravel 5, the `View::make()` facade method from the [2013 accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341826/1255289) has been deprecated. Passing data to the view is now done using the `view()` helper function like this:

```
return view("blog", ["posts"=>$posts]);
```

Or, the same thing:

```
return view("blog", compact("posts"));
```

This can be combined with the `with()` method if desired:

```
return view("blog", compact("posts"))->with("message", "Comment posted");
```

Documentation is available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views).

Comment: True, but I still use with() to send bootstrap flash error/success messages to the view. Don't know how that could be done with compact().

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe you can use the two together. `return view("blog", compact("posts"))->with("success", "Hooray!");`

Comment: @miken32 Thx Mike, never knew we could use with() along with compact().

Answer (score 23):

If you want to pass just **one variable** to view, you may use

*In **Controller***

```
return view('blog')->withTitle('Laravel Magic method.');
```

*In **view***

```
<div>
  Post title is {{$title}}.
</div>
```

If you want to pass multiple variables to view, you may use

*In **Controller***

```
return view('blog')->withTitle('Laravel magic method')->withAuthor('Mister Tandon');
```

*In **view***

```
<div>
   Post title is {{$title}}.Author Name is {{$author}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for also showing how to use the variable in the blade template.  That's the part I was missing.

Answer (score 14):

You can also pass an array as the second argument after the view template name, instead of stringing together a bunch of `->with()` methods.

```
return View::make('blog', array('posts' => $posts));
```

Or, if you're using PHP 5.4 or better you can use the much nicer "short" array syntax:

```
return View::make('blog', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

This is useful if you want to compute the array elsewhere.  For instance if you have a bunch of variables that every controller needs to pass to the view, and you want to combine this with an array of variables that is unique to each particular controller (using `array_merge`, for instance), you might compute `$variables` (which contains an array!):

```
return View::make('blog', $variables);
```

(I did this off the top of my head: let me know if a syntax error slipped in...)

Comment: please clarify my concept!! `array('posts' => $posts)` i have never seen this kind of Array is this an anonymous Array??? where is its name ?? All i know is that this array has key value pair

Comment: You can call it an anonymous array. So in that case when 'posts' array is passed to the view the key will be used as the name to access the $posts which are there inside the array.

Answer (score 9):

**Tips1:**

> ***Using With(), This is a best practice***

```
return view('about')->withName('Author Willson')->withJob('Writer');
return View::make('home')->with(compact('about'))
return View::make('home')->with('comments', $comments);
```

**Tips2:**

> ***Using compact()***

```
return view(about, compact('post1','post2'));
```

**Tips3:**

> ***Using Second Parameters:***

```
return view("about", ["comments"=>$posts]);
```

Comment: Why best practice tips1? Can't we use type2 directly.

Answer (score 7):

controller:

```
use App\your_model_name;
funtion index()
{
$post = your_model_name::all();
return view('index')->with('this_will_be_used_as_variable_in_views',$post);
}
```

index:

```
<h1> posts</h1>
@if(count($this_will_be_used_as_variable_in_views)>0)
@foreach($this_will_be_used_as_variable_in_views as $any_variable)
<ul>
<p> {{$any_variable->enter_table_field}} </p>
 <p> {{$any_variable->created_at}} </p>
</ul>

@endforeach
@else
<p> empty </p>
@endif
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
use TCG\Voyager\Models\Jobtype;

class FormController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
   $category = Jobtype::all();
   return view('contact', compact('category'));

}
}
```

- use your model
- assign it to a variabel
- pass the object to the view
  Here is an example:

Answer (score 5):

You can also do like this

```
$arr_view_data['var1'] = $value1;
$arr_view_data['var2'] = $value2;
$arr_view_data['var3'] = $value3;

return view('your_viewname_here',$arr_view_data);
```

And you access this variable to view as `$var1`,`$var2`,`$var3`

Answer (score 4):

***You can also do the same thing in another way,***

If you are using PHP 5.5 or latest one then you can do it as follow,

## Controller:

```
return view(index, compact('data1','data2')); //as many as you want to pass
```

## View:

```
<div>
    You can access {{$data1}}. [if it is variable]
</div>

@foreach($data1 as $d1)
    <div>
        You can access {{$d1}}. [if it is array]
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Same way you can access all variable that you have passed in compact function.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data to the view using the with method.

```
return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your table data to view using compact.

```
$users = RoleModel::get();
 return view('super-admin',compact('users'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write for passing multiple data from your controller to a view

```
 return \View::make('myHome')
            ->with(compact('project'))
            ->with(['hello'=>$hello])
            ->with(['hello2'=>$hello2])
            ->with(['hello3'=>$hello3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK all the answers tell you how to pass data to the view but no one explains how to read it in the view .
if you use  :

```
 //Routes/web.php
 ...
 Route::get('/user', function () {
    return view('profile', [
       'variable1' => 'value1' ,
       'variable2'=> 'value2' , // add as much as you want
    ]);
 });
```

To read these variables use in your views (in this example it's `profile.blade.php` file):

```
@if($variable1)

 <p> variable1 = {{  $variable1  }}</p>

@endif
```

Laravel does all the necessary work and creates `$variable1` for you .

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have an array with your data.

```
$array1  =  $data;
$array2 = $data;
```

From your controller you can pass this variable using compact. You can pass as many array as you want.

```
return view('data.index',compact('array1','array2'));
```

Here data is a folder in view and index is the file with extension index.blade.php

In view you can call the arrays like this

```
@foreach ($array1 as $something)
   // some operation
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if the variable name is `$posts` then we're passing an `associative array` where the key is `posts` and the value is the `$posts` array you want to pass.

```
return View::make('blog', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

Or we can use the `with` method to pass data.

```
return view('blog')->with('posts', $posts);
```

In your `Blade` view, you can access the `$posts` variable using Blade syntax like this:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{-- Your code to display each post --}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -6):

For any one thinking it is really tedious in the case where you have tons of variables to pass to a view or you want the variables to be accessible to many views at the same, here is another way

In the controller, you define the variables you want to pass as `global` and you attribute the values to these variables.

Example `global $variable; $variable = 1;`

And now in the view, at the top, simply do

`<?php global $variable;?>`

Then you can now call your variable from any where in the view for example

```
{{$variable}}
```

hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is bad advice.  You can easily pass data to a view in the controller why would you want to put it in global scope?  @tkc

Comment: you might override one of laravel's global attributes and break everything apart !