# Laravel 4 error: Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have made a list query that populates my drop down box. I have tried var_dump on the controllers part and it all went well, but whenever I tried to call my function on my blade template, it would return me an error: Undefined variable: categories (View: C:\wamp\www\airlines\app\views\content\onewayflight.blade.php)

What seems to be the problem here?

**OnewayflightController.php**

```
   public function onewayflight()
{ 
  $categories = DB::table('oneways')->lists('destination-from');
  return View::make('content.onewayflight')->with('destination-from', $categories);
}
```

**onewayflight.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::select('destination-from', $categories) }}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('flight/onewayflight','OnewayflightController@onewayflight');
```

Comment: similar question : [**`how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use in Blade:

```
{{ Form::select('destination-from', $destination-from) }}
```

because in your method you used:

```
with('destination-from', $categories)
```

so you told that in Blade `$categories` have to be named `$destination-from`

However you cannot use `-` in variable name, so you should probably change it into:

```
with('destinationFrom', $categories)
```

and in Blade:

```
{{ Form::select('destination-from', $destinationFrom) }}
```

Comment: I bet `$destination-from` is not a valid variable name. `${'destination-from'}` could work tho.

Comment: @Jari I know, I added extra explanation to my answer

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Thank you sir! Now, This is clear to me. An added question sir, What if I'd be populating two separate drop down? How can I correctly implement it?

Comment: @staphhelpme If you use the same data, you simple create new select using the same data (of course other select name). And if you need more data, you need to pass array in `with` method

Comment: I'd be getting different content from different column but place it on the same blade template.. I have tried copying the working code and change the necessary details but it would give me unidentified variable..

Comment: @staphhelpme you need to use `->with(['destination-from'=> $categories, 'other-variable' => $user]);` and so on

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Yes! Thank you so much sir! One last thing, would it be possible to filter the results because in my db entries, I've got repeating content. If so, can you give me an idea?

Comment: @staphhelpme If you have other question, you need to ask new one with explaining all the details so it would be clear

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Okay sir. Again, Thank you so much for your time and help! Really appreciate it!