# Laravel record display from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this leftJoin in my Laravel project

```
products = DB::table('products')
->leftJoin('destinations','products.id','=','destinations.product_id')
->get();
```

Tables:
Product: id,name Destinations:id,product_id,destination,quantity,target_person

but i don't knwo how to display leftJoin,(i just want to display name form product and quantity,destination ,target_person from destinations)
and i want to add new record
This is my form :

```
 <form action="." method="POST" id="formid">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="first_name">Product name</label>
           <input class="form-control" name="name" >
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="last_name">Quantity</label>
           <input  class="form-control"  name='quantity'>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="last_name">Destination<label>
          <input  class="form-control"   name='Destination'>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="last_name">Target Perosn</label>
          <input  class="form-control"   name='target_person'>
     </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

i never do this,please help me this,im beginner in this.

Comment: How to pass data to view.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37559664/5350773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have mentioned, **I just want to display name from product and quantity,destination ,target_person from destinations**. You have to use table `alias` like:

```
products = DB::table('products as t1')
->leftJoin('destinations as t2','t1.id','=','t2.product_id')
->select('t1.name', 't2.quantity', 't2.destination', 't2.target_person')
->get();
```

Comment: I get the following error:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Check the updated answer, instead of table name use `alias` in on clause, I forget to update that part

Comment: Worked,and how can i add new record with the same leftJoin? i try to read laravel documentaion,but im beginner with laravel

Comment: Run two different query, first one for `products` table, get the `inserted id` and then run another query for `destinations` table with the product `inserted id`

Comment: public function  index(){

    

   $products = DB::table('products as t1')
  ->leftJoin('destinations as t2','t1.id','=','t2.product_id')
  ->select('t1.name', 't2.quantity', 't2.destination', 't2.target_person')
  ->get();
      
    

    return view('welcome' , compact('products'));
    }

this s my index method,iwant to display this records,but it doesn't work

Comment: Just only show name ,but i want to three more
So when i pass this data to the view and try to foreach them,only show name