# How to pass data from controller to view in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need to pass data from controller to view this is code :

Controller :

```
function requete()
{
    $id = Str::random();  
    return view('Demo.requete', compact('id'));
}
```

View :

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('support.requete') }}",
        method: "get",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#code').html(data.id);//nothing happens here
        }
    });
});
```

I keep getting this error :

[image]

Comment: Do you want a view as the result or the random string? Because the answer depends on what you want as a result.

Comment: The result must be inside the view not the view.

Comment: then you should pick the answer of Mihir Bhende as his answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data to view in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 3):

You can do :

```
return view('Demo.requete', compact('id'));
```

Then you can use `{{ $id }}` directly in the  blade file.

**Update :**

You are using ajax so you will need a json response :

```
return response()->json(compact('id'), 200);
```

Then you can do in ajax success :

```
$('#code').html(data.id);
```

Comment: Uodated muy answer

Comment: You don’t really need to pass “data” and “dataType” since you aren’t doing anything with it sever side. And if you are trying to access data.id you need to return a JSON response from the server instead of a view. See my answer below on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn’t return a view with an Ajax request, that should be a different route to hit with the $.ajax get request. Laravel can then return JSON responses and you can use that in your success callback.

Yo

```
return response()->json([‘id’ => $id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use **echo** in the view.
You shouldn't use ajax to get the view (unless you want to receive HTML and it does not seem the case here)
You should have a different endpoint for your ajax request if you want to fetch the data asynchronously otherwise you can just return the view with all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

In case of ajax, try returning response json

```
function requete()
{
    $id = Str::random();
    return response()->json([
     "id" => json_encode($id)
   ]);
}
```