# Error when passing a variable from Controller to View Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I tried to pass a variable from Controller to View in Laravel with a simple variable, but It caused an error: Underfined variable.

I tried to change:

```
return view('home', $Test);
```

or

```
return view('home', 'Test' => $Test);
```

or

```
return view('home')->with('Test');
```

My Controller:

```
        public function index(){
           $Test = 55;
           return view('home',compact('Test'));
          }
```

My view

```
            <html>
             <body>
              <h1> {{$Test}} </h1>
             </body>
            </html>
```

This is error:

```
ErrorException {#229 ▼
  #message: "Undefined variable: Test"
  #code: 0
  #file: "E:\Desktop\aroundtrips\storage\framework\views\245291ca31ad79efeff6d548bc38081345e95242.php"
  #line: 78
  #severity: E_NOTICE
}
```

Comment: There might already be an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel/37559664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it like below

```
return view('home', ['Test' => $Test]);
```

For reference check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views

Comment: Thanks guy, I don't know why, but the only solution that I install laravel project with specific 5.7 version is best solution, I think 5.8 version has changed something

Answer (score 0):

Just using `compact('Test')` is going to pass your variable to the view.

So if you leave your controller and view as shown in your question it's going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('home')->with('Test', $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially had same problem with Laravel 5.7 where the `with()` method must be used to pass the variable to the blade template. But I have tested your original code on my own Laravel 5.8 setup and it works flawlessly:

```
public function index()
{
    $Test = 55;
    return view('home', compact('Test'));
}
```

Comment: It still has a error like this:
ErrorException {#227 ▼
  #message: "Undefined variable: Test"
  #code: 0
  #file: "E:\Desktop\aroundtrips\storage\framework\views\245291ca31ad79efeff6d548bc38081345e95242.php"
  #line: 78
  #severity: E_NOTICE
}
1

Comment: if you upgraded to Laravel 5.8 from a previous version, make sure you run `vagrant provision` in homestead directory and retest your site.  Also, ensure  `composer.json`  is the latest version.