# Undefined variable in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have issue with the undefined variable in Laravel 8, I actually don't understand why this happen because I was trying and playing with the Laravel 8.

I created the same method and same coding but somehow when I tried to run the coding for page `about` I got the error that said

> ErrorException
> Undefined variable: about (View: D:\Server\htdocs\app\resources\views\pages\about.blade.php)

Why is this happening ? I don't understand. Because I use the exact same coding for my other pages and it works but when I try to open the `about` page it suddenly give me the error when other pages are perfectly fine with no error.

`PagesController`

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        $title = "Welcome to my blog";
        // return view ('pages.index', compact('title')); // first method 

        return view ('pages.index')->with('title',$title); // 2 method 
    }

    public function about()
    {
        $about = "About Page";
        return view ('pages.about')->with('about',$about);
    }
    
    public function services()
    {
        $data = array(
            'title' =>'Services' // array
        );
        return view ('pages.service')-> with($data);
    }
    
    
}
```

`about.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
 
 @section('content')
        <h1>{{$about}} </h1>
        <p> This is about pages </p>
@endsection
```

`index.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
 
 @section('content')
        <h1>{{$title}} </h1>
        <p> This is tutorial </p>
@endsection
```

Just to show you the same coding i use for `index` and `about`

My route if anyone asking

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class,'index']);
Route::get('/about', [PagesController::class,'about']);
Route::get('/services', [PagesController::class,'services']);
```

`index.blade.php`
[image]

`about.blade.php`
[image]

Comment: are you sure this is the only 'action' that is returning this specific view?

Comment: yes. I got no error for the index page and the service page except for this `about` page. My coding for `index` page and `about` page are same. Which is why I dont understand why I got this error. When I have no problem with the index page

Comment: that isn't what I am asking ... do you have any other actions that are returning this view named `'pages.about'`?

Comment: oh im sorry. I misunderstood you. No, I dont have any other actions that return to this 'pages.about`

Comment: if that is the action you are hitting then I don't know why it would be undefined at the moment, sorry

Comment: yeah its fine. I'm kinda confused too right now. Thank you

Comment: did this get resolved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to view in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function about ()
{
    $ about = "About Page";
    return view ('pages.about') -> compact ('about');
}
```

Replace it as is and try it: your error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Clearing the route cache helped me.
My variable was added later and data was output from the cache

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How is the route cache related to this error message?

Comment: Probably, the variable was added later and data was output from the cache

Comment: ....from the route cache? Also, please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Answer (score -1):

for people still suffering from this issue , head over to web.php and make sure you dont have a duplicated route.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should having a route duplicated cause the given problem?