# Laravel 8 sending data from controller to blade

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8, laravel-7

Hey i need to send data from my controller to view. Following is Route code when user type

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/About** a controller will be activated. But an error is thrown and I have no clue what to do. Any hint or solution will be welcomed :)

Following is the code

**Route**

```
Route::get('About','App\Http\Controllers\Users@about');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Users extends Controller
{
    public function about(){
        $name = "Tony Stack";
        return view('aboutus')->with('name', $name);
    }
}
```

**Blade Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>About Us page</h1>
    <?php echo $name;?>
 <br>   
    <br> <br>
    <a href="About">About Us</a> <br>
    <a href="Contact"> Contact</a><br>
    <a href="/"> HOME</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\storify\resources\views\aboutus.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/About
```

Comment: Note that the duplicate has an outdated answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37559664/1213708 is more up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
return view('aboutus', compact('name'));
```

Here in compact's parameter you have to pass variable name without `$` sign in qoutes. Then in blade file you can access the passed value like `$name`