# Why is my code showing this error: Undefined Variable

Tags: laravel, undefined-variable

I am trying to migrate my foreign key and display the list of employees in company form. for that:

1.My CompaniesController

```
    public function index(){
    $cat = Company::all();
    return view(view:'company/index')->with ('cat', $cat);
}
```

2. This my company migration show:

   ```
    public function up() {
      Schema::create('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('emp_id');
        $table->foreign('emp_id')->references('id')->on('employeee')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('companyname')->nullable();
        $table->string('connumber')->nullable();
        $table->string('addressline1')->nullable();
        $table->string('addressline2')->nullable();
        $table->string('contactnumber')->nullable();
        $table->string('suburb')->nullable();
        $table->string('state')->nullable();
        $table->string('postcode')->nullable();
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
   ```

   }

This is my code for the dropdown menu

```
    `<div class="col-md-6">
      <select name="">
      @foreach ($cat as $row )
     <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->companyname}}</option>
        @endforeach
               </select>
                    </div>`
```

This is admin route for the company:

```
      Route::resource('/admin/companies', 'Admin\CompaniesController',['as'=>'admin']);
```

`

Please Help me out

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the full error page and try the answer down

Comment: @MostafaHana [please do not encourage ppl to post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to view in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // this is how to send the variable to the view
    public function index(){
       $cat = Company::all();
       return view('company/index', ['cat'=>$cat]);
    }

@foreach ($cat as $row)
   <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->companyname}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: return view(view:'company/index', ['cat'=>$cat]); in this statement it says cannot use positional arguement after named arguement

Comment: `return view('company/index', ['cat'=>$cat]); ` without the second view

Comment: I edited my solution up there, sorry for that.

Comment: thank you so much it solved my problem but can you help me with foreign key as well

Answer (score 0):

```
    return view('company/index')->with('cat', $cat);
```

you can try it. remove `view` in brackets and remove space `with('cat', $cat);`.

Comment: thank you so much but can you also help me with foreign key. is the code in migration section right? i'm very confues

Comment: In company model you can use relation like
***
public function employees(){
return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'id', 'employee_id');
}
then write in controller like
$cat = Company::with('employees')->get();
return view('company/index')->with('cat', $cat);
***

Comment: In company model you can use relation like `public function employees(){ return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'id', 'employee_id'); }` then write in controller like `$cat = Company::with('employees')->get(); return view('company/index')->with('cat', $cat);`

Comment: @BarshuMhzn Your migration is fine. What I don't understand is why you have your company name column as `nullable`. You are displaying company names on your drop down menu so if you have it as `nullable` then you'll end up displaying blank options.