# How to display data passed to Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How to display variable ['attributes'] & ['products'] separately in blade

```
$data = [];

$data ['attributes'] = Attribute::active()->whereNull('option_id')->get();
$data ['products'] = Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

return view('dashboard.productOption.edit', compact('prOption','data'));
```

Comment: I advise you check out the Blade documentation to see how to display data in a Blade view: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to view in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You call them as you would any other `associative` `array` element:

```
@foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute)
  <p>{{ $attribute }}</p>
@endforeach
```

The same applies for accessing `products`.