# Laravel looping in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
Route::get('/pizza', function () {
    $edibles = [
        'fruits' => 'Apple',
        'beverage' => 'Milo',
        'soup' => 'Egusi',
        'drink' => 'cocacola',
    ];

    return view('pizza', $edibles);
});
```

```
@foreach ($edibles as $data)
    {{ $data }} 
@endforeach
```

It has been saying

> Undefined
> ErrorException
> PHP 8.1.6
> 9.42.2
> Undefined variable $edibles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to view in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
return view('pizza', $edibles);
```

To this

```
return view('/pizza', compact('edibles'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked buh I am actually more curious on how it worked !! Please can we talk better

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to send backend data to front end.

1. **Without compact function you can send variable and its data as single variable name**
   Here you can set a key name of passing data like ediblesData and get on front side with same name inside foreach loop.

Ex: `return view('pizza', ['edibles' => 'edibles']);`

2. **With compact function you can send variable and its data as single variable name**
   Here you cannot set a key name of passing data and you need to get same key name on front end side.

Ex: `return view('pizza', compact('edibles'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/pizza', function(){
         $edibles = [
            'fruits' => 'Apple',
            'beverage' => 'Milo',
            'soup' => 'Egusi',
            'drink' => 'cocacola',
        ];
        return view('pizza', compact('edibles'));
    });
```

Comment: **compact()** takes a variable number of parameters. Each parameter can be either a string containing the name of the variable, or an array of variable names. The array can contain other arrays of variable names inside it; compact() handles it recursively. reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: So if you wish to send variable to a view, you should use **compact ()** & you'll have to remove the $ sign.

Comment: Please add some verbiage to the changes proposed in your solution. Just the snippet doesn't catch eyes of the readers on what exact changes/fix are/is proposed

Answer (score 0):

You can use compact to send the data. Try this for your case:

```
return view('pizza', compact('edibles'));
```